# Prove the following limit using the N-delta definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} {\ln x} = -\infty$

My attempt:

$\forall\ N<0,\ \exists \ \delta>0 \ st. \forall x,\
c < x < \delta + c \implies f(x) < N$

Let $N$ be given. 
Consider $\ \ln x < N$ 
$\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;  \; \; \; \;  \;  e^{\ln x} < e^N$  
$\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;  \; \; \; \;  \;  x < e^N$

so I set $\delta = e^N$.

The correct solution is $\delta = \frac{1}{e^m}$, and I'm not sure how they arrived at that.

Can anyone show me the way they arrive at that with a little explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work is correct. But usually, the statement is:

$$\forall \ M > 0, \  \exists \ \delta > 0, \  0 < x < \delta \implies f(x) < -M. $$

That is, $M$ is taken positive.

In this case, the choice would be $e^{-M}$, which is $1/e^{M}$.

Note that this is equivalent to what you have done:

You arrived at $\delta = e^N$, where $N < 0$. Now write that as $\delta = 1/e^{-N}$, and here $-N > 0$. That's the same thing.